# Multidimensional array

Tags: c++

The question is to find the output of the follwing program.
This came out in my test and i got wrong. My answer was 4, 7, 10. The answer is 4,8,12 but i need an explanation on how it works

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int number = 4;
    int array[] = {7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
    int *p1 = &number ;
    int *p2 = array;
    int *p3 = &array[3];
    int *q[] = {p1,p2,p3};

    cout << q[0][0] << endl ;
    cout << q[1][1] << endl ;
    cout << q[2][2] << endl ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can simply execute the code for instance on ideone: http://ideone.com/DPdvKx

Comment: I knew the answer , i just wanted an explanation on how this works

Comment: Then please edit your question to state this. It should say, I thought the answer is ... because ... while it is ... why is that so?

Comment: done edited the question

Answer (score 3):

What you have is *not* a multi-dimensional array (C++ doesn't really have it). What you have is an array of pointers. And pointers can be indexed like arrays.

In "graphic" form the array `q` looks something like this:

```
+------+------+------+
| q[0] | q[1] | q[2] |
+------+------+------+
    |     |       |
    v     |       v
+------+  | +-----+----------+----------+-----+
|number|  | | ... | array[3] | array[4] | ... |
+------+  | +-----+----------+----------+-----+
          v
          +----------+----------+-----+
          | array[0] | array[1] | ... |
          +----------+----------+-----+
```

---

Some notes:

What most people call multidimensional arrays are actually arrays of arrays. Much like you can have an array of integers, or like in the case of `q` in your code an array of pointers to integers, one can also have an array of arrays of integers. For more "dimensions" it's just another nesting of arrays.

As for why pointers and arrays both can be indexed the same way, it's because for any array *or* pointer `a` and (valid) index `i`, the expressions `a[i]` is equal to `*(a + i)`. This equality is also the reason you can use an array as a pointer to its first element. To get a pointer to an arrays first element one can write `&a[0]`. It's equal to `&*(a + 0)`, where the address-of and dereference operators cancel each other out leading to `(a + 0)` which is the same as `(a)` which is the same as `a`. So `&a[0]` and `a` are equal.

Comment: great ASCII art :)

Comment: How did you generate the ASCII art though ?

Comment: @PRP Just wrote it straight into the answer. :)

Comment: What is the definition of *multidimensional array* that isn't completely described by *an array of arrays* (recursively of course to account for higher dimensions than 2)? Why isn't an array of arrays *really* a multidimensional array?

Comment: @user2079303 It's more a question of terminology and semantics. It would be a very different case if C++ had [jagged arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) (which can be implemented using classes).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that would indeed be quite different. I would agree that Java has no multidimensional arrays because it has no what are arrays of arrays in C++ sense - instead, it can only have arrays of references to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`q[0]` is in fact `p1`, `q[1]` is in fact `p2` and q[2] is `p3`.

Now p1 is the address of `number` so p1[0] is simply the value of number which you correctly computed to be 4.

`p2` points to array so p2[1] is the same as array[1] which is the **second** element in array ot `8`.

`p3` points to the subarray of `array` starting from position 3. So `p3[2]` is the same as `array[3 + 2] = array[5]` = 12.